# Plink occasionally stalls on error, but does not exit until user presses key

Tags: batch, port-forwarding, plink

I am working on a batch script to automatically remote port forward. The batch script is as follows:

```
start cmd.exe /k "FOR /L %%N IN () DO plink.exe -v -ssh -batch  -C -T -N -R 3389:127.0.0.1:3389 USER@SERVER_IP -P PORT -i privateKey"
```

The problem is that while this works initially, after a while it will stop working and the port will no longer be forwarded. What is weird is that even though there is an error, the plink command does not exit which would allow a new plink session to start. Instead, it just "stalls" with no error. I have to manually press enter for the error to appear and for the command to exit. Since I want this to be automated, is there a way that I can run this so on errors, plink will exit without needing user input?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a file.bat to do this?

---

```bat
@echo off 

cd /d "C:\folder\to\plink"
.\plink.exe -v -ssh -batch  -C -T -N -R 3389:127.0.0.1:3389 USER@SERVER_IP -P PORT -i privateKey

%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1
```

---

In additional about:
*The problem is that while this works initially, after a while...*

It seems to me that you need to use something like **keep alive**, see this **[answer/SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53175117/8177207)**